Firebase Android - The client has already been terminated
I am trying to access the Firebase storage reference in my app but facing an issue while doing it.
Here is how I initialized the Firebase storage,
// Initializing FirebaseFirestore
val mFirebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(firebaseApp)
val settings = 
     FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build()
mFirebaseFirestore.firestoreSettings = settings

// Initializing Firebase Storage
val mFirebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(firebaseApp)

And here is how I am using the Firebase storage reference to upload files to storage,
val storageRef = mFirebaseStorage.reference

// Uploading file to storage
storageRef.child("some-dummy-file-path").putFile(fileUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.v(kTag, "File upload succeed")
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.v(kTag, "File upload failed")
                }

I am getting exception while accessing the storage reference,
val storageRef = mFirebaseStorage.reference

Here is a Stack trace for reference,
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: The client has already been terminated
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.verifyNotTerminated(FirestoreClient.java:11)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.write(FirestoreClient.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:59)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(DocumentReference.java:2)
       at codes.pratik.utils.FileUploader.uploadFileToFireStore(FileUploader.java:70)


Do you call terminate() on the client somewhere? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77262189
